# Vertically split half of the screen with Bootstrap - 4 to display the image till the edge of the screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having a difficulty to develop something like on 1-left-side-full-image.jpg with Bootstra-4 .container class.

I have explained the target (1-left-side-full-image.jpg) the issues (2-background-image-outside-container.jpg, 3-container-fluid.jpg, 4-container-only.jpg)

[image: This is what I am trying to do. An image stretched untill the screen edge]

[image: Background image before .container class makes the image stretched the whole screen]
[image: But not the content on the right, the has also stretched almost to the edge of the screen. As .container-fluid width is 100%]

[image: Using .container makes the form right, the image on the left can not go beyond the width of .container class.]

```
Well Here's a codepen link https://codepen.io/srmahmud2/pen/vaONJQ
```

Comment: Problem solved. please check the Codepen link above or here. [link](https://codepen.io/srmahmud2/pen/vaONJQ)  

What I did here, is   
1. I have put a div right before the class .container and made it position:absolute;   
2. But before that the wrapping section was made position:relative;   
3. Set it with a desired width, in this case a width of BS .col-5 = 41.666667%;  
  
These are main key points, rest you can design as you like.   
  
- Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. please check the Codepen link above or here. [link](https://codepen.io/srmahmud2/pen/vaONJQ)
HTML

```html
<h1 class="text-center">Split half width Background iamge <br>till edge of the screen.</h1>
<section>
  <div class="img-wrapper"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="offset-sm-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="text-content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit iusto adipisci, perspiciatis quo animi vel eum dicta id ut asperiores, consequuntur nostrum tenetur sapiente. Neque incidunt ullam minima eius repudiandae, atque deleniti! Pariatur ea doloremque ex optio ducimus dicta alias!</p>
          <p>Id quot maiestatis vix. Putent virtute iracundia no duo. Eum debitis qualisque deseruisse ei, te nec omnis verear virtute. Te recusabo explicari deterruisset vim. Eu perfecto consequuntur mel, ex mea blandit verterem temporibus. Mei tota definiebas ne</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="text-center">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h2>The End</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```html
h1{
  margin:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
section{
  padding:30px 0;
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom:80px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
div.img-wrapper{
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1229846/pexels-photo-1229846.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940");
    min-height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
/*   change the left side image width as like you want */
    width: 41.66667%;
    left: 0;
}
p{
  padding: 20px;
}
```

What I did here, are
1. I have put a div right before the class .container and made it position:absolute;
2. But before that the wrapping section was made position:relative;
3. Set it with a desired width, in this case a width of Bootstrap .col-5 = 41.666667%;

These are main key points, rest you can design as you like.

@mahan See the image bellow, in your case the background image is not cover the whole space esp it should occupy the whole screen and start immediately from the left side of the content.

@david-liang I am sorry if my words have filed to describe what it is. But in your case the image is covering the whole area, however it seems the image is partially seen.

Well, We may leave the rest for the visitors to decide which one is correct.

Here the compared image in all cases how it looks. 
[image]

- Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You want to do something like this?

[image]

You can achieve this by combining the background image and linear-gradient.

```
section {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, #fff 50%), 
        url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/731082/pexels-photo-731082.jpeg?
            auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940') no-repeat top left;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The idea here is to load the background with linear gradient first, 50% transparent on the left and 50% white on the right, and then load the background image.

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-6">
               ...
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/94438/

What cool about this approach is, you can put a degree of angles into `linear-gradient()` to make even cooler backgrounds (IMO), like this:

[image]

with just a change to the `linear-gradient()` function

```
background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 50%, #fff 50%),
    url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/731082/pexels-photo-731082.jpeg?
        auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940') no-repeat top left;
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for trying to solve my issue. Well I still have some thing add for your solution.
1. The image is stretched, and not position in center form both horizontal as well as vertical.
2. It's not responsive. Try Ctrl + (-)

Please check the link here that is responsive and positioned in the center.  [link](https://codepen.io/srmahmud2/pen/vaONJQ)

Comment: @MahmudurRahman: 1) It's so easy to change background-position to center it from both horizontal as well as vertical. I used top left on my example because I saw you did the same on your OP codepen example. 2) It depends on what you want to do on small screens. My solution is indeed responsive. On the smallest screen, it just hides the background. You haven't defined what you expect in that situation so I just made something up as an example.

Comment: I tried in many ways with your solutions. Sorry! My Bad! Would please share a Codepen link. 
TIA!

Comment: See my updated fiddle link in my post. I centered the background per your request.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a `container`, a `col-6` can have a maximum width of `540px`.

---

- Use `container-fluid` for this section.
- Restrict max-width of the right column to the maximum width that a `col-6` column can have inside a `container`.
- Remove padding of the right column.
- Use `align-items-center` for the row.
- Use `container` for the rest of the code.

```css
.mw-540px {
  max-width: 540px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row  align-items-center">
    <div class="col-6 p-0">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/fuyao/likes" alt=""  class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 pt-5">
      <div class="mw-540px">
        <div>
          <h3>Contact Us</h2>
            <p class="small">
              Vestibulum venernatis id ex eu dapibus. Suspendisse sit amet justa leo. Curabitur ornare tacus erat, ac interdum liguta consequat ut. Fusce id tellus ac ante feugiat porta.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <p>
            <i class="fa fa-phone fa-fw"></i> +1234567890
          </p>
          <p>
            <i class="fa fa-email fa-fw"></i> ABC@ABC.COM
          </p>
        </div>
        <form>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cell" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur rerum numquam voluptatibus cum! Impedit dolore hic repellendus, itaque rem perferendis vitae similique, voluptatum debitis dolorem ex quaerat eligendi vel qui? Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius ad accusantium assumenda deleniti neque quia voluptatibus optio cumque reiciendis numquam labore placeat sunt et architecto natus, delectus adipisci odit nobis? Quasi nesciunt rerum odit aliquam totam. Harum,
        et! Voluptas omnis animi sequi id officia ipsum, nihil repellendus officiis ratione eum nostrum expedita culpa delectus laboriosam explicabo consequuntur aut ab ad? Magnam voluptate quam tenetur minima. Voluptas nam odit dolores, similique earum
        obcaecati quo alias maiores harum necessitatibus eveniet, consectetur ipsa expedita sunt corporis, explicabo corrupti temporibus? Qui ipsa officia dignissimos?
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur rerum numquam voluptatibus cum! Impedit dolore hic repellendus, itaque rem perferendis vitae similique, voluptatum debitis dolorem ex quaerat eligendi vel qui? Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius ad accusantium assumenda deleniti neque quia voluptatibus optio cumque reiciendis numquam labore placeat sunt et architecto natus, delectus adipisci odit nobis? Quasi nesciunt rerum odit aliquam totam. Harum,
        et! Voluptas omnis animi sequi id officia ipsum, nihil repellendus officiis ratione eum nostrum expedita culpa delectus laboriosam explicabo consequuntur aut ab ad? Magnam voluptate quam tenetur minima. Voluptas nam odit dolores, similique earum
        obcaecati quo alias maiores harum necessitatibus eveniet, consectetur ipsa expedita sunt corporis, explicabo corrupti temporibus? Qui ipsa officia dignissimos?
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OwyRLL

---

Keep in mind that I have used `Unsplash` photo. Some of them may have a very large height. In that case, refresh the page.

Comment: The major issue in here it's not responsive. Please check my Codepen link [link](https://codepen.io/srmahmud2/pen/vaONJQ)

Comment: Could you elaborate on `it's not responsive`? It is responsive